# How to use wildcards to find the emails in outlook using python?

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, wildcard

I am trying to single out emails in Outlook that have specific characters in their subject line.
I am not able to use any wildcards in python to search through the emails. Does anyone know how to do that?

Below is my code:

```
from win32api import MessageBeep, MessageBox
import win32com.client
import datetime
import re

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("Folder")

messages = inbox.Items

for message in messages:
    if message.subject == "5th 1-33 for November": #This is where I want to use the wildcard to replace the '5th'
        print("Found")
```

Thanks in advance for all your help.

I searched all the questions but did not get the answer I was seeking.

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to loop through all messages in a folder just like you don't want to run a SQL statement without a WHERE clause. Use `Items.Restrict` or `Items.Find/FindNext` with a query similar to

@SQL="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F" LIKE '%1-33 for November'

Where `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F` is the DASL name of the `PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT` MAPI property